Rerun Snowflake tasks on failure with a larger warehouse automatically
We have a snowflake task that is taking longer time than expected time. we would want to customize task so that if it takes more than 10 mins, it should fail and restart the same task with a different warehouse of larger size. Please help how this can be achieved

This doesn't sound like a good idea to me but if you really want to do this then I think you'd need to do the following:

Create an SP that runs on a schedule of your choosing
In the SP, query for the failed task you want to re-run
In the SP , alter the task to change the warehouse to a different one (or create a new task)
In the SP, execute the task
In the SP, (if you need to) alter the task to revert back to the original warehouse

Update
If you know you'll get large loads from the source on a regular basis (e.g. every Monday) then you could create a separate task with a larger warehouse, schedule that task on Mondays and stop the original task from running on Mondays.
You might also like to consider the cost of running the larger warehouse for all executions of the task (even when it might be overkill) v. the cost of building and managing a process to deal with occasional overruns

Is this query always taking longer than 10 minutes to complete or only some  time it is longer, if it is that way then you need to identify any other queries running which is taking up the resource.

not all the times. the query is taking time only when we get huge loads from source.

Hi I think then one option is to check the load if it is huge (crossing a certain number of rows) then do what was suggested by @NIckW.

You can also try and see if Snowflake's query acceleration service (QAS)  will improve your query performance   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-acceleration-service
